# relating GCD, congruency and congruent classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

So some of you may have noticed my algebra exam is tomorrow!

The question is: If $[a]_{n} = [1]_{n}$ prove that $\mathrm{gcd}(a, n) = 1$.

Well I tried it one way. We know the above means the following: $a \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. This is also written as $1 \equiv a \pmod{n}$
Then the gcd of these are  as follows:
$$\mathrm{gcd}(a, n) := d  $$ and 
$$\mathrm{gcd}(1, n) := d'.$$

At this point I thought $ d = d'$ which is NOT the case as pointed out by roommate. but lets assume it does so I finished the proof as follows:

$$\mathrm{gcd}(a,n) = \mathrm{gcd}(1, n)$$
$$\mathrm{gcd}(a, n) = 1$$

but then obviously that's not the case (or is it). I then tried the following:
$$d = as + nt,  \quad s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
$$d' = as' + nt',  \quad s', t' \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

And now I'm stuck again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the GCDs are the same, but your argument shows a lot of confusion, as Bill points out. First, when you claim that $d=d'$, the problem is that you are simply *asserting* a result that is *stronger* than what you are trying to prove. You are trying to prove the simpler case that if $a\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ then $\gcd(a,n)=1$, and you are invoking the result that if $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ then $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)$. That's **more** than what you want to prove, so you cannot simply *assume* it's true.

But really, think about $[a]_n = [1]_n$. That means that $1 = a+kn$ for some integer $k$. That means that you can write $1$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $n$. That means that $\gcd(a,n)$ divides $1$. That means...

Comment: We actually tried that, but we dont know what to do after? I tried the linear combination way but how do we end the proof using that?

Comment: @Tyler Hinton: So, you know that the gcd divides $1$. You should also know that the gcd is positive. How many positive integers do you know that divide $1$?

Comment: ohhhhh i only know of one positive integer that divides one. which is 1. awesome. didn't even think that way! so does that complete my proof?

Comment: @Tyler Hilton: Well, that completes *my* proof; if you write it up properly, then it will also be your proof. (-;

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ d\:|\:n,\:1+kn\ \Rightarrow\ d\:|\: 1$

Comment: hey thanks, but we were right the first time. The GCD of those two are the same.

Comment: What you wrote above shows confusion about basic points. I recommend that you write out your purported proof here so that we can help you further.